# DataGridView Data Filter

Tags: c#, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

How to filter data in DataGirdView. This DataGridView is developed  from Managed Host control in Ax 2012. All the values are filled dynamically but need to add filter like the standard Ax Forms.

Thanks,

Comment: You you use a DataSource? If not, consider using it; it has a simple Filter property!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what you mean exactly with "add filter like the Standard Ax Forms" and I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this, here is my take on adding a simple filter function to an AX form that uses a `DataGridView` managed host control to display data.

This is based on the tutorial [Using Managed Host Control in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012](http://www.dynamics101.com/2015/03/using-managed-host-control-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012/), to which I added a `StringEdit` control to enter the filter criteria and a button to remove the filter.

In the `modified` method of the `StringEdit` control the rows of the `DataGridView` are cleared and refilled with the values according to the filter criteria. Variable `filterValue` is the `StringEdit` control with `AutoDeclaration` set to `Yes`.

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret;
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection      rowCollection;
    System.String[]                                     strValues;
    CustTable                                           custTable;
    str 20                                              filterValueStr;

    ret = super();

    filterValueStr = filterValue.text();
    rowCollection = dataGridView.get_Rows();
    rowCollection.Clear();
    while select * from custTable where custTable.AccountNum LIKE filterValueStr
    {
        strValues = new System.String[2]();

        strValues.set_Item(0, custTable.AccountNum);
        strValues.set_Item(1, custTable.name());

        rowCollection.Add(strValues);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

The `clicked` method of the button to remove the filter basically executes the same code that is used to initially fill the rows of the `DataGridView`.

Here is an .xpo with the whole example of [MyDataGridViewFormWithFilter](https://goo.gl/DbAUZ8)

Comment: Hi FH_Inway,
           This is good answer but I am not exactly looking for this solution. I have a large amount of data and secondly user make changes in data which I need to post after operation.By your post when ever user filters I need to save in table and retrieve data which would be very slow and space consuming because of large amount of data. Can you suggest any alternative?